# Suppose we have the following data. How can we calculate the channel capacity and R?

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

A channel has a bandwith of 5MHz. If signal strength to spectral noise density S/N<sub>0</sub> is 10<sup>7</sup> Hz, calculate the channel capacity C and R. The problem
is that I can use Shannon-Hartley theorem because instead of S/N or SNR I have
S/N<sub>0</sub>.

Comment: Hint: If you have $N_0$, and you have the bandwidth, can you find $N$?

Comment: I suppose you mean that N = BN<sub>0</sub>. So by that I can finally find that S/N = 2. From that I can calculate C. But how can I calculate R?

Comment: @MBaz I thought that R <= C but I am not sure that's the case.

Comment: if $R$ is the information rate, then you're right, $R\leq C$.

Comment: @MBaz Yes, R is the information rate. I suppose that from the data available I can't compute a value for R. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: all you can say is that, as long as $R\leq C$, you can theoretically transmit the information with as few errors as you wish. So, there is no single number for $R$ that you can provide as answer (given the problem as you have stated it).